# POST request variables powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, escaping, string-interpolation, invoke-webrequest

I have a powershell post request using `Invoke-WebRequest` but when I include the ? it thinks its all one variable, any way to escape this, here is my code

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method POST https://192.168.240.1:443/recive/$name?result=$sendback
```

It thinks name and everything after is a variable, I know this as I can see it all highlighted green in winddows terminal

Comment: Backtick young grass hopper (`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complement [jswanson's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638177/45375):

While placing `` ` `` (a backtick, PowerShell's escape character) before the first post-variable-name character is *situationally* an option<sup>[1]</sup> (in unquoted and double-quoted arguments), there is a ***direct* way to delimit variable names** in (implicit) [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375): **Enclose the name in `{...}`**, e.g. `${name}`:

```bash
Write-Output https://192.168.240.1:443/receive/${name}?result=$sendback
```

While something like **`${name}?`** is more cumbersome to type than `` $name`? ``, it has two distinct **advantages**:

- It is more readable (visually distinct).
- It works in *all* cases, whereas `` ` ``-escaping the post-name character could accidentally turn that character into an [*escape sequence*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters); e.g., say variable `$foo` should be followed by literal `bar`:

  - `` Write-Output $foo`bar `` - *Broken*, because the `` `b `` becomes a *backspace character*.
  - `Write-Output ${foo}bar` - OK, thanks to `{...}` enclosure

---

**Optional reading: Why does PowerShell allow `?` in identifiers (variable names)?**

Most scripting and programming languages do not allow `?` to be part of identifiers such as variable names, typically because `?` is a [metacharacter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) (a character with special meaning).

Even though `?` in PowerShell has special meaning too, depending on context, `?` in identifiers (variable names, function names, alias names, ...) *are* permitted.

While it is commendable on the one hand that PowerShell allows identifiers containing unusual characters, *it would make sense to require `{...}` enclosure* for such names<sup>[2]</sup> - as indeed is already required for *other* unusual characters, notably `.` and `-`:

```bash
# With ".", {...} is required.
PS> ${foo.bar} = 'bar'; ${foo.bar} # Without {...}, .bar would be a *property access*.
bar
```

Regrettably, **use of `?` does *not* require `{...}`**:

```bash
# !! With "?", {...} is NOT required.
PS> $foo? = 'bar'; $foo?
bar
```

This behavior **actively interferes with the [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.1+ [null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-conditional-operators--and-), `?.` and `?[]`**.

For instance, say I want null-conditional access to a property of variable `$var`:

```bash
# FAILS, because "?" is considered part of the variable name.
Set-StrictMode -Version 3; $var = Get-Item foo*.txt; $var?.Length
```

The error message is `InvalidOperation: The variable '$var?' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.`; that is, expression `$var?.Length` was interpreted as wanting to perform *regular* property access (`.`) on a variable named `$var?` - instead of the intended null-conditional access on variable `$var`.

**`{...}` is *required* in this case even though the name `$var` itself does *not* contain special characters**:

```bash
# OK, due to {...} - but this shouldn't be necessary
Set-StrictMode -Version 3; $var = Get-Item foo*.txt; ${var}?.Length
```

Given that this is **both counterintuitive and cumbersome**, [GitHub proposal #11379](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11379) asks for this behavior to be changed. Even though it is technically a *breaking* change, analysis has revealed that real-world use of variable names *ending* in `?` is vanishingly rare and that, conversely, such use was often *erroneous*, i.e. based on the expectation that a trailing `?` is *not* a part of a variable name.

---

<sup>[1] It is only an option if the `` ` `` in combination with the first post-variable-name character doesn't accidentally result in an [*escape sequence*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters); as would happen with `t`, for instance.</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that given that only *variable* names, not also functions, ..., support `{...}` enclosure, this would limit `?`-containing names to variables.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

As @Abraham Zinala implies, The versatile Backtick (`) is an escape character in PowerShell.  You can verify the effect by changing the placement of a Backtick in this line

```
echo https://192.168.240.1:443/recive/$name?result=$sendback
```

I believe what you are looking for is this

```
echo https://192.168.240.1:443/recive/$name`?result=$sendback
```